# Installing PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

This is my 2nd day at trying to [install PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/install/), so please go easy on me.
Here's what I did starting this morning:

```
C:\Users\Phillip> npm install -g phonegap
C:\Users\Phillip> phonegap create my-app
C:\Users\Phillip> cd my-app
C:\Users\Phillip\my-app>phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js
:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_m
odules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.
js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\co
rdova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.
js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modul
es\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Edit 1:

```
C:\Users\Phillip\my-app>phonegap platform add android
   [error] 'platform add android' is not a node C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js command. See 'node C:\Users\Phillip\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js help'
```

Edit 2:

```
C:\Users\Phillip\my-app>%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\che
ck_reqs.bat
[Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets]
```

Edit 3:

```
C:\Users\Phillip\my-app>npm install -g cordova
```

Edit 4:

```
C:\Users\Phillip>cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello"
 at location "C:\Users\Phillip\hello"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Download complete
C:\Users\Phillip>cd hello
C:\Users\Phillip\hello>cordova platform add ios
Downloading cordova library for ios...
Download complete
Creating ios project...
'C:\Users\Phillip\.cordova\lib\ios\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create' is not recognized a
s an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Comment: Please follow the CLI guide here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface 
If any pieces of that guide are not clear then feel free to let me know and we can add any missing information.

Comment: Have you installed sdk platform for api 19? (target sdk is set to 19 for 3.3)

Comment: Did you add `npm` and `node_modules` to your PATH as specified in the docs? "NOTE: The -g flag above tells npm to install cordova globally. You may need to add the npm directory to your PATH in order to invoke globally installed npm modules. On Windows, npm can usually be found at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm and on Unix at /usr/local/share/npm."

Comment: Go to the command line and type `android`. Download the latest API level. Use that android tool to create an AVD (android virtual device), which is needed for the tools to have a "target" to compile against. Understand that there is real functional difference between cordova and phonegap, so you don't need to install both, one or the other should be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add your platform and build it first

```
npm install -g phonegap
phonegap create my-app
cd my-app
phonegap platform add android
phonegap platform build android
phonegap run android
```

And maybe use your cmd.exe in administrator mode. I lose so much time because of this..

Comment: when you call "run" it actually does add, prepare, build and then run.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. But I think the administrator part can be helpful.

Comment: @QuickFix are you sure about that? I know that `build` will take care of running `prepare` and `compile` but I'm pretty sure that's all it does. You have to add the platform first, and then run `build`, and then `run` to launch the app on a device.

Comment: actually that's true for phonegap cli but not for cordova (but here the question was about phonegap). And it's the process described in phonegap docs : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: I followed this thread exactly, and I still get errors [error] 'platform add android' is not a node

Comment: please see if this helps you out. http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2014/04/creating-phonegap-project-with-android.html

Comment: I m getting this error Plaform add android is not a node.

Answer (score 2):

Check you have all the requirements listed in [the cordova platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html)

I recently discovered a magic command that helps display what's missing to build cordova android project :

```
%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that check_reqs script will be called automatically when you use the CLI to add platforms.

Comment: actually it's called when adding the platform but doesn't display clear result as when launched directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the following commands:-

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
$ phonegap create my-app


$ export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/taruna/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/taruna/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/toolssource
```

The above path should be your sdk tool path.

```
$ phonegap run android after
```

Now the above command will run your application in the emulator.It may take several minutes, so please wait for that and check the result.

Also, you should have node.js installed in your system before making any phonegap project using CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this blog helps you with the proper installation and check all the steps described are followed. [Installing cordova phonegap](http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2014/04/creating-phonegap-project-with-android.html)